# ExtJS 4 pagination with local store

Tags: javascript, pagination, extjs4, store, paging

I have a grid which uses a local store, that is created with an array. I tried to use this solution: [Paging toolbar on custom component querying local data store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13778444/paging-toolbar-on-custom-component-querying-local-data-store) 
but it doesn't seem to work.

My code:

```
    var myData = [];
    //... fill myData

    var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore', {
        fields: fields,
        data: myData,
        pageSize: 10,
        proxy: {
            type: 'pagingmemory'
        }

    });


    // create the Grid
    var table = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        id: "reportTable",
        store: store,
        columnLines: true,
        columns: columns,
        viewConfig: {
            stripeRows: true
        },
        dockedItems: [{
            xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
            store: store,
            dock: 'bottom',
            displayInfo: true
        }]
    });
```

Without this part of code the grid is showed but pagination doesn't work. With it the whole grid doesn't appear at all.

```
    proxy: {
        type: 'pagingmemory'
    }
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: What is the problem? Is there an error? What does the myData variable look like? Try creating a standalone test at http://fiddle.sencha.com.

Comment: The problem is that the pagination doesn't work and the grid isn't showed though without pagination it works fine. myData contains rows for the grid.

Comment: can you post the code on jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, the problem is that the PagingMemoryProxy.js is not being loaded.
Make sure you are loading this script explicitly (since this is part of 'examples', it is not part of the ext-all ) You can find this under  `<extjs folder>\examples\ux\data\PagingMemoryProxy.js`

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
  enabled: true
});

Ext.Loader.setPath('Ext.ux', 'examples/ux');

Ext.require('Ext.ux.data.PagingMemoryProxy');
```

Answer (score 0):

In some ExtJS versions (ie. 4.2.2) the use of `pagingmemory` proxy is depracated.

Use the [`memory`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Memory) proxy with [`enablePaging`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Memory-cfg-enablePaging) configuration instead:

```
proxy: {
    type: 'memory',
    enablePaging: true,
}
```

Check the documentation of your ExtJS version to see if this configuration is enabled in your version.